# fabric-ca not starting when building network with artifacts created using cryptogen and configtxgen

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am following this repo to build a network and use java sdk to create a small block chain application.

In this repo there is already a directory named network-resource where all the artifacts are present and the build.sh script work with these artifacts.

But when I try to generate the artifacts and build the network peers are started but fabric-ca is not started.

Details below.

crypto-config.yaml file

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    # EnableNodeOUs: true
    CA:
        Country: US
        Province: California
        Locality: San Francisco
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    CA:
        Country: US
        Province: California
        Locality: San Francisco
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "CA"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of the CA for this
    # organization.  This entry is a Spec.  See "Specs" section below for details.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # CA:
    #    Hostname: ca # implicitly ca.org1.example.com
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specs:
    #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org1.example.com"
    #     CommonName: foo27.org5.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
    #   - Hostname: bar
    #   - Hostname: baz
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Template"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
    # from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
    # You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
    # or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
    #
    # Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
    # sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
    # name collisions
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Template:
      Count: 2
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    CA:
        Country: US
        Province: California
        Locality: San Francisco
    # CA:
    #    Hostname: ca # implicitly ca.org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

configtx.yaml file

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # AnchorPeers:
        #     # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        #     # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        #     # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        #     - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
        #       Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        # AnchorPeers:
        #     # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        #     # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        #     # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        #     - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
        #       Port: 7051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2

################################################################################
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

networks:
  custom:

services:

  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/26447f667024067fc5efbd2605f92b410dc2d0ce10408890949eb71ac7fbe2f9_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - custom

  ca.org2.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/384b0c0e6faf5d2c256f1265a89aecde606e7577869e07f3e1b17ad318607413_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - custom

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    networks:
      - custom
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ../network_resources/config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg2

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_custom
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    networks:
      - custom
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ../network_resources/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_custom
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    networks:
      - custom
    ports:
      - 7056:7051
      - 7058:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ../network_resources/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_custom
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    networks:
      - custom
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ../network_resources/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_custom
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    networks:
      - custom
    ports:
      - 8056:7051
      - 8058:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../network_resources/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ../network_resources/config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
```

This is the build.sh script I use.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

set -e
export IMAGE_TAG=1.4
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
mkdir config
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID mychannel
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
```

This script generates artifacts which I replaced with the artifacts present inside network-resources.

Then I use the following command to bring the network up.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Here is the problem the above command spins only 4 peers and one orderer.
Not the two ca present in docker-compose.yml file.

The strange thing is that when I use the artifacts provided in the github repo the above steps spins ca also.

Comment: Github repo I am following https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do the logs say?
Use

```
docker logs ca.org1.example.com -f
```

And paste them here.

It might be because of the FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE as it changes each time you run the cryptogen.

Comment: the container is not starting so I cant take log

Comment: you have 2 options here.
1. Add this to your container:      ` restart: always ` so you can check the logs.
or
2. Check stopped containers by doing: `docker ps -a` and then with the id `docker logs imageid`

Comment: Its was the key issue. I am supposed to update the FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE value when I generate artifacts. Thanks

Comment: glad it helped :)